# Using NHibernate to query with NOT IN in the WHERE clause

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Take this query as an example:

```
select * from publisher 
where id not in (
    select publisher_id from record 
    where year = 2008 and month = 4
)
```

Can anyone help me on how I could build and run this query using NHibernate? Assume that I have 2 classes: `Publisher` and `Record`.

Thanks

Comment: What's the connection between publisher and record in your model classes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I'll say that Record has a foreign key to Publisher. It's one->many from Publisher to Record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.For<Record>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Publisher"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Year", 2008))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Month", 4));
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Publisher))
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("Id", c))
    .List();
```